# ¿Como convertir kilobytes a varbinary?

Tags: c#, sql

Siempre que necesito almacenar archivos en una base de datos uso el campo varbinary(max), que es el máximo que soporta el tipo de datos, y simplemente le asigno un arreglo de bytes al campo para almacenarlo, en este momento estoy en la misma situación y me surge una duda, ¿es posible hacer la conversión de kilobytes, que pesa el archivo, a varbinary?, ¿que objetivo tiene esto?, si tengo limitado que se almacene un archivo de 4 mb, puedo definir el campo varbinary del tamaño para almacenar 4 mb y no usar el "max" del tipo de dato.

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación de [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362(v=sql.110).aspx), se debe de utilizar **varbinary(max)** cuando las entradas de datos de columna superen los 8.000 bytes. En este caso convendría realizar la validación del tamaño máximo permitido antes de almacenarlo en la base de datos.

En caso te interese conocer el tamaño de lo almacenado en un campo varbinary(max), puedes referirte al siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428670/calculate-size-in-megabytes-from-sql-varbinary-field).